# Impulse response of a FIR-filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

a have a simple question about a course i've been studying called "introduction to signal processing with matlab". I've been given a FIR-filter with coefficients b=[0.0201 0.2309 0.4981 0.2309 0.0201] and I have to calculate the impulse response. The impulse response from theory is the response of a system to unit impulse as an entry.
the following commants in matlab give the same results:

```
b=[0.0201 0.2309 0.4981 0.2309 0.0201];
impz(b);

OR

b=[0.0201 0.2309 0.4981 0.2309 0.0201];
d_10=zeros(1,50);
d_10(10)=1;
x=conv(b,d_10);
stem(x,'r');
```

Are the results of these two the impulse rensponse of the Fir-filter or a have to do something more? Thank you...

Comment: For an FIR filter, the coefficients _are_ the impulse response. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Agreed.  the FIR coefficients *are* the impulse response.